# Скрыть элементы управления Яндекс Карт

Tags: html, яндекс-карты

Через конструктор создал карту и сгенерировался следующий код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A0ab64bb950e0786a79bc1186aed0b94189f3fb78047803962&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=570&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

Но в инструкции https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/constructor/concepts/About-docpage/ нет ни слова о том, как скрыть элементы управления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что через конструктор невозможно скрыть элементы управления, создал карту по этому примеру: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_and_hint

Определить координаты можно при помощи этого инструмента: https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/location-tool/